# Multiple comparisons for GLMM dataset (proportion/binomial response) - lsmeans?

Tags: r, statistics, mixed-models

[image: results of glmm showing high variance in half of the dataset]

I have a glmm that runs fine, and produces results that makes biological sense. I want to do multiple comparisons with the levels predictor variable I'm interested in (a factor with 6 levels--labeled Body in the diagram). This factor and its interaction with Class were significant in the GLMM (as expected).

I have tried using lsmeans using this code:

```
lsmc <- lsmeans(modelc, ~ Class*Body)
plot(lsmc, by = "Class", intervals = TRUE, type = "response")
cld(lsmc)
```

The result is a confusing mishmash of grouping codes:

```
> cld(lsmc)
Class  Body    lsmean        SE df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL .group    
a      6    -4.134310 0.2707025 NA -4.664878 -3.603743  123      
a      3    -3.970351 0.2728055 NA -4.505040 -3.435662  123      
a      4    -3.928422 0.2704543 NA -4.458502 -3.398341  123      
a      5    -3.882009 0.2692264 NA -4.409683 -3.354335  123456   
b      6    -3.736560 0.4111311 NA -4.542362 -2.930758  1  4  7  
a      1    -3.526359 0.2772493 NA -4.069757 -2.982960     456789
a      2    -3.343117 0.2711772 NA -3.874614 -2.811619        789
b      5    -3.200230 0.4107996 NA -4.005383 -2.395078   2  5  8 
b      1    -2.879111 0.4122133 NA -3.687034 -2.071187   23 56 89
b      2    -2.840026 0.4110968 NA -3.645761 -2.034291    3  6  9
b      3    -2.818114 0.4102995 NA -3.622287 -2.013942    3  6  9
b      4    -2.649563 0.4096440 NA -3.452450 -1.846675    3  6  9
```

As far as I am aware, non-continuous grouping codes, as seen in all of Class b aren't a good sign.

Is there another way to go about multiple and/or pairwise comparisons with output from GLMMs?

Comment: If you need advice with a statistical analysis, you should be asking your question on [stats.se]. This does not appear to be a specific programming question.

Comment: Groupings can be non-contiguous whenever the standard errors of differences vary. For example, suppose you have observed means of 10.0, 10.1, and 11.0 with sample sizes of 2, 1000, and 3 and a pooled SD of 0.40. Then the largest and smallest means are not significantly different, but the second and third are.